# Cannot define a big matrix and it's slow with malloc in C

Tags: c, matrix, memory, malloc

I am trying to declare a matriz `memo` with `MAX 2000000000` size. The problem is that I obtain this error when compiling:

```
error: size ‘16000000016000000004’ of array ‘memo’ exceeds maximum object size ‘9223372036854775807’
   10 | int memo[MAX + 1][MAX + 1];
      |     ^~~~
```

I understand that it is a memory problem but I dont know how to solve it. I've tried to declare `memo` with malloc before the `while` loop of main such as here:

```
int **memo = (int **)malloc((MAX + 1) * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) {
        memo[i] = (int *)malloc((MAX + 1) * sizeof(int));
    }
```

But it is too slow for me, does anyone knows an efficient way of declaring this matrix? I also have to reset the matrix values to `-1` every time I scan new values.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 2000000000 //tiene que ser 2.000.000.000

unsigned int n1,n2,f1,f2;
int i,j;
char next_char;

int memo[MAX + 1][MAX + 1];

void scan_fast(int* int_input){
    *int_input=0;
    next_char=0;
    while( next_char < '0' || next_char > '9' ) // Skip non-digits
        next_char = getchar();
    while( next_char >= '0' && next_char <= '9' )
    {
        (*int_input) = ((*int_input)<<1) + ((*int_input)<<3) + next_char - '0';
        next_char = getchar();
    }
}

int comida(int f1, int f2) {
    /* Se ha terminado el caso */
    if (f1 == 0 && f2 == 0){ return 1; }

    if (memo[f1][f2] != -1) {
        return memo[f1][f2];
    }

    printf("f1: %d, f2: %d\n", f1, f2);
    
    if (f1 >= n1 && f2 >= n2 && comida(f1 - n1, f2 - n2)) {
        memo[f1][f2] = 1;
        return 1;
    } else if (f1 >= n2 && f2 >= n1 && comida(f1 - n2, f2 - n1)){
        memo[f1][f2] = 1;
        return 1;
    } else {
        /* No se ha podido encontrar con este caso */
        memo[f1][f2] = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    
}

int main() {
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &f1, &f2, &n1, &n2);

    while(!(f1 == 0 && f2 == 0 && n1 == 0 && n2 == 0)) {
        /* Resetear la matriz */
        for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= MAX; j++) {
                memo[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }

        if (comida(f1,f2)) printf("SI\n");
        else printf("NO\n");

        scan_fast(&f1); scan_fast(&f2); scan_fast(&n1); scan_fast(&n2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're asking for an array with 4 **quintillion** elements.  You don't have that much memory.  Why do you think you need an array of that size?

Comment: @dbush true omg that is like 6Gb of matrix, I am trying to know which proven cases i ve made in a deep search (function `comida`)

Comment: Where do you expect that memory to be located? I doubt you have enough RAM for that. Even disk space will hardly be available to hold that beast. You need to think about some mechanism to solve your problem without needing such a monster array.

Comment: Some sort of sparse matrix structure *might* work better depending on what you're trying to calculate.

Comment: "that is like 6Gb of matrix" more like 4EB (exabytes, i.e. 2GB x 2GB)

Comment: @Shawn thank you! That's what I' going to try

Comment: @dbush More like 16EB (assuming 32-bit `int`). Virtually all of 64-bit address space.

Comment: (2 000 000 000² * 4) / 2 ^60 = (almost) 14 exbibytes. Yep

Comment: Just buy more memory. At say US$5 per gigabyte, you will need just about $80,000,000,000.

Answer (score -2):

The solution to this problem is not to locate this matrix but using an **sparse matrix**, where I locate only the elements that aren't -1 (initial value for my program)